# file_get_contents not retrieving page contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

OK, before saying this is a duplicate just read a bit....
I have been trying to echo contents of URL that has `allow_url_fopen` disabled for HOURS now, I have tried every solution posted on stack overflow. EXAMPLE:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Doesn't WORK

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Doesn't WORK

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Doesn't WORK

```
fopen("cookies.txt", "w");
$url="http://adfoc.us/1575051";
$ch = curl_init();

$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: adfoc.us',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:adfoc.us',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Doesn't WORK

```
// create the Gateway object
$gateway = new Gateway();

// set our url
$gateway->init($url);

// get the raw response, ignore errors
$response = $gateway->exec();
```

Doesn't WORK

```
$file = "http://www.example.com/my_page.php";
if (function_exists('curl_version'))
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
else if (file_get_contents(__FILE__) && ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
}
else
{
    echo 'You have neither cUrl installed nor allow_url_fopen activated. Please setup one of those!';
}
```

This doesn't work.

The page I am trying to use `file_get_contents` on is not on my website. I am trying to use `file_get_contents` so i can make a simple API for the site owner by reading a page and checking if a certain word is present on the page.

But yeah if anyone has any suggestions PLEASE post below :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check first weather the site is available or not for example a sample code

Code taken from [here](http://www.technofusions.com/curl-in-php-tutorial-basics/):

```
<?php
    $cURL = curl_init('http://www.technofusions.com/');
    curl_setopt ( $cURL , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
    // Follow any kind of redirection that are in the URL
    curl_setopt ( $cURL , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true );
    $result  =  curl_exec ( $cURL );
    // Getting  HTTP response code
    $answer  =  curl_getinfo ( $cURL , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    curl_close ( $cURL );
    if ( $answer  ==  ' 404 ' ) {
      echo  ' The site not found (ERROR 404)! ' ;
    } else {
      echo  ' It looks like  everything is working fine ... ' ;
    }
  ?>
```

For a full answer you can got to this tutorial [Curl IN PHP](http://www.technofusions.com/curl-in-php-tutorial-basics/)